# Voltage output in ripple filter

Tags: capacitance, resistors

[image]

we got this ripple filter circuit as shown in this figure.Input voltage

$$ V=v(1+\cos (\omega t)) $$

is fed to left input and then find output voltage. Now this problem confuses me. For instance I cannot figure out if they are parallel or series? And therefore I could not found impedance to find the output voltage. How do I proceeded in this problem?

Comment: Hint: It's a voltage divider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now this problem confuses me for instance i cannot figure out if they
>   are parallel or series

Parallel connected circuit elements share the same voltage across, series connected circuit elements share the same current through.

In this case, and by KCL, it is clear that the capacitor current is identical to the resistor current so the resistor and capacitor are series connected.

> and therefore could not found impedance to find the output voltage

Well, you must proceed carefully here if you plan to use an impedance approach as your input voltage is the sum of a constant and a sinusoid

Since the impedance of the capacitor is "infinite" for a constant voltage, the constant term passes through to the output unchanged; only the sinusoid is affected.

For the sinusoidal component, there is attenuation by the factor:

\$\dfrac{1}{1 + j \omega RC} \$